# One-loop correction to triple gluon vertex in QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, brst, ghosts

I'm trying to calculate a one loop correction to the 3 gluon vertex, which is given by a circular correction, and another that's due to the 4 gluon vertex.

However I'm unsure how the ghost fields enter into the correction. Since we have a gluon-ghost-ghost vertex, can we have something like a closed ghost loop in addition to the diagrams given above? As far as I'm aware this is allowed since the ghosts are forming a closed loop.

[image: one loop corrections to the 3 gluon vertex]

Comment: The Feynman rules associated to ghosts depend on the gauge fixing choice. Guess you are using Feynman gauge or some other $\xi$ gauge, right?

Comment: That's correct, I'm using a generalized $R_\xi$ gauge.